# GCM communicate with others activites

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using gcm to get event from my server, this works fine but I'd like to communicate with others activities using my class GCMIntentService

I have my method to receve messages

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
// Get the data from intent and send to notificaion bar
generateNotification(context, intent);
}
```

I'd like for exemple to send datas to my MainActivity but I can't find how to do that
I just find:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

But in my case I don't want to start a new activity I just want to send datas to a running activity.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think this answer is what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143395/481528

You can also read here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, @selalerer thanks for your help

In a first time init the receiver:

```
    //receive events
private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
         System.out.println("receive");
     }
}
```

in the onCreate add

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("local");
this.registerReceiver(new Receiver(), filter);
```

To finish send the message with

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction("local");
i.putExtra("test","test");
sendBroadcast(i);
```