# How to pass intent with extras to an already running activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which launches a `HomeActivity` with some information passed with the extras.

What happens when the activity is already running and the broadcast receiver gets triggered again which tries to launch the `HomeActivity` with new info. Does the `OnResume()` or `OnCreate()` of the activity execute?

If not, is there any other way of passing/reloading a running activity when a `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered?

Comment: Perhaps this may answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143222/sending-data-to-another-activity-that-may-be-started (you have to override onNewIntent() ). I'm not sure though.

Comment: You need an `Interface`.  Define a callback.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Make sure when you are launching the intent from the BroadcastReceiver you set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag.

```
intent.addFlags (FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

...


class HomeActivity extends Activity {
   ...
   @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is classic answer. Thank you @Cory you saved my day

Answer (score 6):

Just extending Cory Roy's answer you have to define "SingleTop" in AndroidManifest.xml too.

```
<activity
        android:name="MainActivity"            
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

It seems that extending android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity this method does not work...

Comment: this does not seem to be necessary! This means that the default launch mode is 'singleTop'. you might not want that and only for notifications

Comment: Worth noting that launchMode only needs to be set either in the manifest or via addFlags() from the calling intent, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Forget starting activities from a Broadcastreceiver, google added since Android 12 a trampoline prevention.
See docs:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12