# How to pass an intent back to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My app has a `RecyclerView` in the `MainActivity` with an onClickListener which sends an intent to a `DetailActivity`. The `DetailActivity` has a button to go back without doing anything and a button to send an intent to the `Activity.
I already checked other posts in here like [How to pass intent with extras to an already running activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672482/how-to-pass-intent-with-extras-to-an-already-running-activity)  and others, but no one results.

Here is a version that I tried:

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    int codPedido = getIntent().getIntExtra("CodPedido",1);
    
    //Toast to test if it's working
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(codPedido), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

OnClick of RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("CodigoPedido", pedidos.get(i).getCodPedido());
intent.putExtra("Local", pedidos.get(i).getLocal());
intent.putExtra("Dia",pedidos.get(i).getDia());
intent.putExtra("Periodo", pedidos.get(i).getPeriodo());
intent.putExtra("urgente", pedidos.get(i).isUrgente());
intent.putExtra("requisitante",pedidos.get(i).getRequisitante());
intent.putExtra("observacoes", pedidos.get(i).getObservacoes());
```

DetailActivity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_confirm) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CodPedido", codPedido);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Edit:**

This is what I tried now:

```
    viewHolder.clRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CodigoPedido", pedidos.get(i).getCodPedido());
            intent.putExtra("Local", pedidos.get(i).getLocal());
            intent.putExtra("Dia",pedidos.get(i).getDia());
            intent.putExtra("Periodo", pedidos.get(i).getPeriodo());
            intent.putExtra("urgente", pedidos.get(i).isUrgente());
            intent.putExtra("requisitante",pedidos.get(i).getRequisitante());
            intent.putExtra("observacoes", pedidos.get(i).getObservacoes());
            mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

and it gives `method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference`

What I was doing before was using the context which is here in the constructor

```
public RvPedidosAdapter(List<Pedido> pedidos, Context context) {
    this.pedidos = pedidos;
    this.context = context;
}
```

like this:

```
    viewHolder.clRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CodigoPedido", pedidos.get(i).getCodPedido());
            intent.putExtra("Local", pedidos.get(i).getLocal());
            intent.putExtra("Dia",pedidos.get(i).getDia());
            intent.putExtra("Periodo", pedidos.get(i).getPeriodo());
            intent.putExtra("urgente", pedidos.get(i).isUrgente());
            intent.putExtra("requisitante",pedidos.get(i).getRequisitante());
            intent.putExtra("observacoes", pedidos.get(i).getObservacoes());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578803/4247543

Comment: Use `setResult` ,`startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`

Comment: @RissmonSuresh I can´t use startActivityForResult from recyclerViewAdapter

Comment: Can you specify what do you need? Like Activity 1 send to Activity 2 X and then from Activity2 receive it bla bla, with more details?

Comment: Activity1 -> startActivityForResult, 
Activity2 -> setResult, 
Activity1 -> onActivityResult

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS click on recyclerViewItem to send values from an object I created to DetailActivity then if click on accept send an int value back to MainActivity

Comment: @RajatMehra the problem is the startActivityForResult has to be in the recyclerViewAdapter and it don't let me.

Comment: You can pass `Activity mActivity` to the recyclerViewAdapter and then call `mActivity.startActivityForResult`

Comment: @trivatus look at the edit: please! with context I can't use startActivityForResult(), and the context is MainActivity.this

Comment: You should pass `Activity` when initializing the adapter.

`private Activity mActivity;
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Activity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
}`

Comment: Or you can define `RecyclerViewAdapter` as non-static class in `MainActivity`, so that you can call `startActivityForResult` directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    On Your code please pass startActivityForResult() with intent param with result code and get the result on MainActivity in onActivityResult();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("CodigoPedido", pedidos.get(i).getCodPedido());
    intent.putExtra("Local", pedidos.get(i).getLocal());
    intent.putExtra("Dia",pedidos.get(i).getDia());
    intent.putExtra("Periodo", pedidos.get(i).getPeriodo());
    intent.putExtra("urgente", pedidos.get(i).isUrgente());
    intent.putExtra("requisitante",pedidos.get(i).getRequisitante());
    intent.putExtra("observacoes", pedidos.get(i).getObservacoes());
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    On your second activity please use this code.
    Intent intent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CodPedido", codPedido);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

and move to your MainActivity.class to get the result data in onActivityResult() method like this.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
             (data.getIntExtra("CodPedido");          
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
`startActivityForResult(Intent intent,int requestcode);`

Comment: This is a low-quality answer. Why not explain the implementation of `startActivityForResult` to OP?